# Passing Data Between View Controllers Not Working

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sdk

I am attempting to pass the label for a given selected cell to a different view controller...

ListViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle: nil];
DetailViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailVC"];
viewController.venueName = cell.textLabel;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

}
```

Here is my DetailViewController:

.h

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *venueName;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *venueName;
```

venueName never gets the data. In my .m I also synthesize the venueName.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your UILabel outlet is not connected at the time you set a string for it. I recommend you to create a string property to store the value and, in viewDidLoad in DetailViewController, you set the string to venueName.
Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the below like that for setting and getting the text:-

```
viewController.venueName.text = cell.textLabel.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

So `venueName`, which is a *pointer to a label*, is made to point to an existing label that's part of a table cell. This is obviously wrong -- you don't mean to use the actual label from the table cell, but rather the text stored in it. Both the other answers here are correct: you surely mean to assign the `text` property of one label to that of the other, and the label that outlet `viewController.venueName` is connected to hasn't been created at the time this code executes.

The immediate thing you should do to fix your code is to assign the data in question (i.e. `cell.textLabel.text`) to a string property in the destination view controller. Have the `-viewDidLoad` or `-viewWillAppear` method in that controller set the `text` property of the `venueLabel` label. Either of those methods will be called after the view hierarchy is instantiated.